# Powershell 2 event handling

Tags: events, powershell, powerpoint

I'm trying to script Powerpoint with Powershell 2.0.

This [site](http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html) says there's a "PresentationOpen" event. However, Get-Member does not show this event. Also, when I try to do this:

```
register-objectevent $application PresentationOpen notification_event
```

it says: "Cannot register for event. An event with name 'PresentationOpen' does not exist."

Why is this event not accessible from PowerShell? Am I doing it wrong, and there is another way?

What I'm really trying to do is to wait until the presentation is fully loaded before I save it in another format. Not waiting causes PPT to freeze sometimes.

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Could you please add the entire code block you are trying to use?

Comment: I tried the code you posted below in a Powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is pretty weak in COM support (it's a lot more like C# than it is like VB). In this case, you'll have to delegate the event. See the dispatches on this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308825/EN-US/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm pretty illiterate in PowerShell, so I have no idea what to do now, that is a bit too advanced for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be other (and better) ways to do this, but this should get you started:

```
$ppa = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$eventId = Register-ObjectEvent $ppa PresentationOpen -Action { "Hi" }
$ppa.Visible = 1
$ppa.Presentations.Open("Path\To\Presentation.ppt")
```

You would want to replace the script block after -Action on the second line with whatever code would do the processing/saving.

If there is any output from your event that you have registered, you can deal with it through the Receive-Job cmdlet, otherwise you can just simply add a loop similar to this right after the Open() method call to block further script execution until the slide deck has finished opening:

```
While ((Get-Job $eventId).State -neq "Completed") { Start-Sleep -m 250 }
Receive-Job $eventId
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I try this, I get: Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot register for event. An event with name 'Presentat
ionOpen' does not exist.